# Show that $f(x,y) = \cos(x+y)+8$ is continuous at $(0,0).$

Tags: real-analysis

I tried the following for this problem:

We first compute $f(0,0) = 9.$ Next we look at 
$$|f(x,y)- f(0,0)| = |\cos(x+y)-1|\leq \frac{(x+y)^2}{2}$$
when $(x,y)$ is in the neighbourhood of $(0,0).$ Since $\frac{(x+y)^2}{2}\to 0$ as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ we conclude that $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(0,0).$

I am not sure whether this Taylor series type of argument can be applied for functions of several variables. Therefore, I would be grateful if someone could give feedback regarding this problem.

Comment: It's a composition of continuous functions.

Comment: Even though it is very intuitive, perhaps one should add explanation for why $\frac{(x+y)^2}{2}\to 0$?

Answer (score 1):

$$0\le 1-\cos(x+y)=2\sin^2(\frac{x+y}{2})$$

$$\le \frac{(x+y)^2}{2}$$

since

$$(\forall X\in \Bbb R) \;\;\; |\sin(X)|\le |X|$$